# How to display user logged in, directly on the homepage

Tags: php

I am trying to display a very simple button for logged in users directly in my homepage.

I use the very basic login/register that uses include/membersite_config.php file.

I am trying to display a "logout" button for logged in users and a Profile Register button for logged out users.

```
<?php 
 if(isset($_SESSION['username_of_user'])) {
     require_once("./include/membersite_config.php");
     echo '<a class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" href="logout.php">Esci <span class="fui-exit"></span></a>';

    } else {
        echo '<a class="btn btn-warning btn-large" href="membro.php">Profilo</a> <a class="btn btn-prenota btn-large" href="registrati.php">Iscriviti</a> ';
    } 
?>
```

Unfortunaly the code above only works if the page includes this:

```
<?PHP
require_once("./include/membersite_config.php");

if(!$fgmembersite->CheckLogin())
{
    $fgmembersite->RedirectToURL("accedi.php");
    exit;
}

?>
```

If I use this code in the homepage, it will redirect non logged-in users to the login page, and I don't want that.

if i use

> session_start()

I then can't seem to logout form the session

Do I need to use session cookies maybe? I have tried a lot of different combinations but I really can't figure this out. :/ thanks

Comment: did you use `session_start()`?

Comment: I tried to use session_start but when I do, even users that do not have an account, or are not logged in, see the logged in variables, such as the logout button

Comment: **I use the very basic login/register that uses include/membersite_config.php file.** -> And how does the **very basic** login/register looks like? Are you using a framework? Are you using a CMS?

Comment: actually you cannot access `$_SESSION` variables without calling `session_start()` before

Comment: I use Flat UI Pro designer framework. The login/register script is from  HTML Form Guide which can be found here https://shorten.club/VaADU

Comment: it looks like the session_start() is included in the membersite_config.php

Comment: your code works, as you stated, when you include that file, because in that file, `session_start()` is called. as I said, your code won't work without `session_start()`

Comment: Ok, when i use session_start() , the logout works (I then cannot access profile page) but the buttons remain the same.